# Librosa on jython

Tags: jython, librosa

I installed Jython 2.7.1 and want to get librosa to work to get theier mfcc transformations to work. I have issues installing it as it seems to rely on numpy which uses C but Jpython does not do C. I found JyNi as some layer in-between to get this to work. Is there any installation guidance that i could get? (for mac osx)

Regards

Comment: Why do you want to use Jython instead of CPython?

Comment: Because I want to use it directly from java and not through JNI to C :)

Comment: hi have u find some workaround ?